When SP certificates updated, how adfs update its local certificates?
Here is the situation with SSO by saml
SP: our own apps, with a valid certificates which will be expired in 1 year
Idp: ADFS in windows server
The SP federation metadata we configured in ADFS is as below:
enter image description here
And the SSO login works fine.
After 1 year, the SP certificate has been expired， and all the logins have been failed which is also reasonable.
However, after we update the SP certificates, the logins is still keeping failed.
Is there any more work to do with ADFS? Is there a cache of SP federation metadata in adfs, and how long the cache will be expired.
I tried to configure the corresponding content in ADFS from the beginning, and it can work again. But I'm not sure why I have to do this from begining. Is there any clue?
